# Creating NetCDF file with new variables (different dimensions)

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file whose resolution is 9 km (1/12˚).

(Dimensions = 489 x 376 x 20)

Variables: 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Depth', 'Time', 'zu', 'zv' and 'zw'

Now I created new a new mesh that is 2 km.

(Dimensions = 1501 x 1953 x 20)

Variables: 'lon', 'lat, 'Depth', 'zuc', 'zvc' and 'zwc'

**QUESTION**

How can I create a NEW.nc with 'lon', 'lat', 'Depth', 'zuc', 'zvc' and 'zwc'?

**SCRIPT**

```
filename='mydata.nc';

ncdisp(filename);


% Load in variables

Time = ncread(filename,'Time');

Longitude=ncread(filename,'Longitude');

Latitude=ncread(filename,'Latitude');

Depth=ncread(filename,'Depth');

zu=ncread(filename,'zu');

zv=ncread(filename,'zv');

zw=ncread(filename,'zw');


% Permute matrices to be interpolated and create a mesh

[lo, la, dep]=meshgrid(Longitude,Latitude,Depth);

Au=permute(zu,[2 1 3]); 

Av=permute(zv,[2 1 3]); 

Aw=permute(zw,[2 1 3]); 


% Define new resolution @ 0.02

lon=Longitude(1):.02:Longitude(end); lon=lon';

lat=Latitude(1):.02:Latitude(end); lat=lat';

[X, Y, Z]=meshgrid(lon,lat,Depth); % New mesh 

zuc = interp3(lo,la,dep,Au,X,Y,Z); zuc=permute(zuc,[2 1 3]);

zvc = interp3(lo,la,dep,Av,X,Y,Z); zvc=permute(zvc,[2 1 3]);

zwc = interp3(lo,la,dep,Aw,X,Y,Z); zwc=permute(zwc,[2 1 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to know two functions for writing data into netcdf. I am giving an demo example below, you may extend the same to your case, by changing the variable names and dimensions.

```
 % nc filename to be written
file = 'myfile.nc' ;
%% Write lon and lat variables
% Get data
lon = 1:10 ;
lat = 1:10 ;
nx = length(lon) ;
nccreate(file,'lon','Dimensions',{'lon',1,nx},'DeflateLevel',7) ;
ny = length(lat) ;
nccreate(file,'lat','Dimensions',{'lat',1,ny},'DeflateLevel',7) ;
nccreate(file,'time','Dimensions',{'time',1,Inf},'DeflateLevel',7) ;
nccreate(file,'z','Dimensions',{'lon','lat','time'},'DeflateLevel',7) ;
for i = 1:10
    ncwrite(file,'time',i,i)   % write time 
    data = rand(10) ; 
    ncwrite(file,'z',data,[1,1,i]) ;   % write 3D data 
end
```